# How do I run the Spark logistic regression with categorical features using python?

Tags: apache-spark, logistic-regression, categorical-data

I have a data with some categorical variables and I want to run a logistic regression using Mllib , it seems like the model support only continous variables.
Does anyone know how to deal with this please ?

Answer (score 0):

Logistic regression, like the other linear models, takes as input an RDD whereas a LabeledPoint is a Double (the label) and the associated Vector (a double Array).

Categorical values (Strings) are not supported, however you could convert those to binary columns.

For example if you have a column RAG taking values Red, Amber and Green, you would add three binary column isRed, isAmber and isGreen of which only one of them is 1 (true) and the others are 0 (zero) for each sample.

See as further explanation: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.DictVectorizer.html